# Processing 2 folders simultaneously

Tags: python, csh

I am using C shell script. I have 2 directories names dir1 and dir2 and both contains n  number of files. I have to process the files at same time. Let me explain: I have a command that does some processing and gives the output. eg.

```
 score = custom_command (file from dir1 , file from dir2)
```

and I need to do this as a batch processing. How can I write a script to do this?

Here is what I did (algorithm) but it did not work: This is a logical flaw I think.
Any help in doing this in python language is also welcome, I wonder we don't have function to read files through multiple directories.

```
foreach filename1 in dir1
  cd dir2
  foreach filename2 in dir2
    cd -
    score = custom_command ($filename1 , $filename2)
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you using [tag:bash] or [tag:csh]?

Comment: using csh but any algorithm will also work.

Comment: in bash pretty sure you could do something like `for i in /dir1/*;do score=custom_command(dir1/${i##*/},dir2/${i##*/});done`. Also won't your command do the custom command on every file against every file in both directories, not just the corresponding ones.

Comment: s it in Python, I can use python as well for this purpose. If possible suggest some solution in python lang.

Comment: Folks are asking for clarification in their answers, but just to do this right: are you trying to do N^2 processing (each of n files in dir1 against each of n files in dir2) or is there correlation such that you have the exact same files (with different data) and therefore are only doing n processing steps (each of n files in dir1 only against the corresponding file in dir2)?

Comment: It is not N^2. It is like I want to use one file against its corresponding files. e.g. Folder1 has files, f1, f2. f3 and folder2 had files g1, g2 g3 so I will use score1 = custom_command(f1, g1) then in the nest step I would use score2 = custom_command(f2,g2) and so on and keep on saving the score1 score2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to run N^2 processes simultaneously?  Try (in a bourne shell):

```
for f1 in /p/a/t/h/dir1/*; do for f2 in /p/a/t/h/dir2/*; do cmd $f1 $f2& done; done
```

And stop using csh!  (I'm assuming your comment "using csh but any algorithm will also work" is intended to mean "any language will work".)

Comment: Is it in Python, I can use python as well for this purpose. If possible suggest some solution in python lang.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do what you describe in Python:

```
import os
import itertools

dir1='/tmp/x'
dir2='/tmp/z'

files1 = [os.path.join(dir1,x) for x in sorted(os.listdir(dir1))]
files2 = [os.path.join(dir2,x) for x in sorted(os.listdir(dir2))]

def custom_command(file1, file2):
    # Some custom code goes here,
    #   for example, this meaningless drivel
    return os.path.getsize(file1)*os.path.getsize(file2)

for file1, file2 in itertools.product(files1, files2):
    score = custom_command(file1, file2)
    print file1, file2, score
```

Alternatively,

```
import os
import itertools

dir1 = '/tmp/x'
dir2 = '/tmp/z'

def custom_command(file1, file2):
    # Some custom code goes here,
    #   for example, this meaningless drivel
    return os.path.getsize(file1)*os.path.getsize(file2)

for file1 in os.listdir(dir1):
    for file2 in os.listdir(dir2):
        file1 = os.path.join(dir1, file1)
        file2 = os.path.join(dir2, file2)
        score = custom_command(file1, file2)
        print file1, file2, score
```